# AWS EC2 instance with access to S3 bucket for streaming a video

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am quite familiar with EC2 instances, IAM's (users, roles, groups), S3 buckets and policies and hope the community can help me here.

Let's assume I have an EC2 instance with a webserver running. This EC2 instance hosts a web video player (video js, JWPlayer etc.). Ideally I would like to host an MP4 on a S3 bucket without making the S3 bucket public.

My initial thought was that I could either create a role with full access to the S3 bucket or assign a policy to the bucket that allows the instance to have access.

I have tried many policies and roles but neither seem to work. Now I am wondering if this is even possible.

[image: Design]

I understand that this architecture is not perfect and that you would potentially use cloudfront to serve the video. However, this is just a proof of concept...if possible. Thank you guys!!

Comment: A simple IAM role that permits s3:GetObject access to the bucket (or to some subset of it) would allow the EC2 instance to read the MP4 files (assuming you've launched the instance with that IAM role). This assumes that you actually want your web server to read the MP4s and proxy them to the client rather than the client going directly to S3 to get the MP4.

Comment: What do you mean by "neither seem to work"?

Comment: Will [presigned URL's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) work for what you want?

Comment: @jarmod You bring up an interesting point. Does the EC2 instance have to be launched/created with the IAM role or am I able to assign the role at a later point? I am asking because it looks like that you are able to assign a role to a running EC2 instance (could also be misleading)

Comment: @stdunbar Yes, pre-signed URL's would work too. I will definitely play around with that. However, I do like the approach of serving private content via cloudfront (posted below by: John Rotenstein)

Comment: Yes, as of Feb 2017 you can dynamically replace/attach IAM roles to a running EC2 instance.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for your input. Sorry I have to dig a little bit deeper. You mentioned "proxy" in your original answer and I just want to make sure I fully understand "proxy" in that context. There are concepts out there where i.e. an MP4 was temporarily copied to i.e. an EC2 instance in order to play it back (could be caching). This is not what you are referring to, correct?

Comment: If the client can't get a file directly from S3/CloudFront then the client has to get it from your web server. So your web server is proxying the file download (whether you cache it or not). That's all I mean - your web server is sitting between the user and the desired content. That requires you to implement lots of code to get files from S3, support file downloads to the client and, if you want them cached, then manage a cache on EC2. There's a strong argument for removing your web server from that path, allowing the client to go direct to S3/CloudFront.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you so much! That clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect use-case for an Amazon S3 [pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provides time-limited access to a private object. It completely offloads the traffic to S3, making it highly scalable for serving content.

Basically:

- The object is kept private
- Your application determines whether the user is entitled to access the file
- The application **generates the pre-signed URL** with a time limit of, say, 5 minutes
- The application includes the URL in the standard HTML page (eg, if it was an image, use `<img src="...">`

Yes, a user can share the link with other people, but it expires after the given time period.

You can also [Serve Private Content through CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html), which can work better for many media players because it can [serve streaming media](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/).